# Is it possible to save the ISO, aperture, and other settings along with the image?

Tags: canon, raw, metadata, jpeg, camera-settings

Is it possible to have the ISO, Aperture, and other setting save with the JPEG or RAW image when taking photos?

I have the Canon T5i, and I'm fairly new to photography. I can keep a log book with these settings, but I didn't know if there was a way to store this information with the saved image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that information and more is already saved in the EXIF data attached to each image. Any good photo editor will show it to you.

Comment: @GreenChili there's no need to open PS just to view the exif data. That's overkill. Most common operating systems will show the data along the properties of the file. In the file manager of your operating system, try right clicking the file (or whatever it takes to show the properties of the file) and look around for the exif data. If you cannot get it to work, please specify your operating system.

Comment: @null you are absolutely correct. This provided the information I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Photo viewers/managers will do a better job at showing you metadata than editors like Photoshop.  If you have something like bridge, picasa, or whatever you use to manage photos (even Windows' build-in file manager if you have the folder in photo mode), you should be able to do things like sort by aperture, or by shutter speed, and things like that, allowing you to do something like, select all photos I shot with my 18-70mm lens, or all photos I shot where the flash fired.